# How can i have multiple gifs in 1 canvas?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, gif

Photoshop CS6.

I have the following animated gif that i want to put above a big white canvas, in specific positions.

[image: Here is the animation in question.]

[image: This is the white canvas with the position where this gif have to be, copied 4 times.]

However, i don't know how export a gif multiple times, for ALL the frames to be above this white canvas nor move the whole animation to these specific places.

How can i copy this gif 4 times above a white canvas and in these positions?

Comment: This feels like your task is ill-defined, in effect an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) Please tell us what you're actually trying to achieve, rather than ask us about your proposed solution.

Comment: It might sound like an ill-defined task, but it reallly is what i need to do, put the same animated gif, above an image multiple times, in specific places.

Comment: You duplicate the layers for the animation and animate all 4 at once in the same timeline. -- But.. I agree with @Tetsujin this sounds like an X/Y problem.. what's the final output?  I mean it *could* be done in HTML via CSS and z-index to overlay the same image 4 times on a larger area.

Comment: Perhaps best done in video editing software and then converted to gif.